# Not getting messages back from Salesforce Streamping API Push Topic Channel

Tags: salesforce

I have a Push topic I created through Workbench in Salesforce. I'm able to connect to the channel using C# Bayeux client, but not receiving new messages from the channel.

My query is very simple: -

> Select Id, WhoId, Subject From Task

I tried several code examples from available GitHub repos, but none seem to help. 
[https://github.com/foluis/Salesforce_PushTopics][1]
[https://github.com/nthachus/CometD.NET][2]

Also added my IP address to my salesforce instance's trusted IP's

> using (var user = await _service.AuthenticateAsync()) {
>
> var pushTopicClient = new LocalBayeuxClient(user.AccessToken,
>   user.InstanceUrl).CreateClient();
>
> var pushTopicConnection = new PushTopicConnection(pushTopicClient);
>
> pushTopicConnection.OpenClientConnection();
>
> var channel = pushTopicClient.GetChannel("/topic/GetNewTaskNew/");
>
> channel.Subscribe(new TestMessageListener());
>
> ```
>     // my test listener does not receive anything
> ```
>
> pushTopicConnection.CloseClientConnection(); 
>   }

There are no errors / exceptions. Just nothing coming back to me when a new message comes on my channel.

Comment: How do you create these Tasks / can you try with another object? See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/supported_soql.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/working_with_pushtopics.htm. Maybe Change Data Capture (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/understand-change-data-capture) is better for you, similar but more reliable. Streaming API was meant as UI notification when another user changed this record, not really "industrial" strength solution

Comment: Thank you @eyescream and sorry about the delayed response. Task is created by Lead Conversion and it looks like Streaming API won't work in this scenario. For Change Data Capture, is the implementation similar? I subscribe to data/TaskChangeevent/ but nothing still comes across :(. Any thoughts? Thank you again !

Comment: Client implementation for Streaming API vs Platform Events vs CDC should be very similar. The open source tool they use to demo/debug handles all. See "EMP Connector" in https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/subscribe-to-events. If it also doesn't catch these Tasks... well, what if you cheat? Make these tasks from workflow or process builder instead as config option in the conversion?